# Removal of AccordianDetails component from DOM on collapse of material-ui Accordian

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I am using `Accordion` component of `material-ui` in my first React project. I noticed that when the `Accordion` is collapsed, the `AccordionDetails`(being descendent of `Collapse`) is not removed from the DOM. It is only hidden away by changing the height internally. My code is:

```
<Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
```

and in React Developer Tools it looks like this:

```
Accordion
  Accordion.ContextProvider
    AccordionSummary
      ButtonBase
  Collapse
    Transition
      Context.Provider
        AccordionDetails
....
```

How can I collapse the `Accordion` removing the `AccordionDetails` from the DOM and with the default transition?

I could not find any option to do this in [Collapse](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/) and [Accordion](https://material-ui.com/api/accordion/) API documentation.

> Currently installed version:
>
> - react: 16.12.0
> - material-ui: 4.9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component used for the collapse effect or the `TransitionComponent` is the `Collapse` component and by default the child component stays mounted after it reaches the 'exited' state. We can [pass props to it](http://the%20child%20component%20stays%20mounted%20after%20it%20reaches%20the%20%27exited%27%20state) by using `TransitionProps`.

The following code will `unmount` the `AccordionDetails` component being a child component of `Collapse` when `Transition` reaches the exit state or simply when `Accordion` is collapsed.

```
<Accordion TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: true }}>
```

Reference:
http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-unmountOnExit